# GZipStream zip file invalid or corrupted

Tags: c#, zip, unzip, gzipstream

I have a problem when opening a zip file. I am using this code to zip the file:

```
public static string Zip_File(string soruce , string target)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] bufferWrite;               
        using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(soruce, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            bufferWrite = new byte[fsSource.Length];
            fsSource.Read(bufferWrite, 0, bufferWrite.Length);
            using (FileStream fsDest = new FileStream(target, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (GZipStream gzCompressed = new GZipStream(fsDest, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                {
                    gzCompressed.Write(bufferWrite, 0, bufferWrite.Length);
                    bufferWrite = null;
                    fsSource.Close();
                    gzCompressed.Close();
                    fsDest.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

When I call this function, I am receiving "success" message, but I can't open the zip file.  This is my function call code:

```
ZipFiles.Zip_File(@"C:\Documents and Settings\ccspl\Desktop\IntegrityDVR.mdb", @"C:\Documents and Settings\ccspl\Desktop\a.zip")
```

This is the error message I receive:

> the compressed(folder) is invalid or corrupted

Answer (score 8):

`GZipStream` does not create `.zip` files. It creates `.gz` files. If you need to create `.zip` files, you should use something like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/).

Comment: no Mehrdad ... my prob not yet solved... it's giving the same error msg

Comment: RV: Of course **it doesn't create .ZIP files**. You need a program like 7-Zip to open `.gz` files.

Comment: Cheeso: I suggested `Flush` as a way to start troubleshooting. That was before I understood the OP didn't want Gzip at all; he wants Zip.

Answer (score 1):

but, wait a minute, GZipStream doesn't create zip file, it creates gzip files as I know, [Zipping files using GZipStream](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial190_Zipping-files-using-GZipStream.html) should help

Comment: The article you cited, at http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial190_Zipping-files-using-GZipStream.html , is bogus. It repeatedly claims that GZipSream can be used to zip files, or produce a .Zip archive. Not true.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)? It makes this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

sample code for [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com), an open source zip library.

```
public static string ZipFile(String source, String target)
{
    try 
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()
        {
            zip.AddFile(source);
            zip.Save(target);
        }
        return "success";
    }
    catch {}
    return "failure";
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good and very useful library reference, and thanks for correction