# Can't decompress data with GZipStream without running into exceptions, can't determine cause

Tags: c#, .net, gzip, blazor, gzipinputstream

In a Blazor WebAssembly project I'm working on, I am compressing data at a back-end WebAPI server and passing it up to the front-end Blazor server (running Blazor WebAssembly, not "Blazor Server," yay for confusing terminology), to be delivered to the user who then decompresses it. I'm running into the following exception:

> System.IO.IOException: Corrupted data ReadInternal at
> System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative.CheckResult (System.Int32
> result, System.String where) <0x34fa860 + 0x000f0> in :0 at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative.ReadZStream
> (System.IntPtr buffer, System.Int32 length) <0x34f9c60 + 0x00024> in
> :0 at
> System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadInternal (System.Byte[] array,
> System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) <0x34f9a90 + 0x00066> in
> :0 at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read
> (System.Byte[] array, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count)
> <0x34f96e8 + 0x000cc> in :0 at
> System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read (System.Byte[] array,
> System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) <0x34f33b0 + 0x0001e> in
> :0 at
> OptionalyticsFrontend.Shared.Services.Compression.DecompressString
> (System.Byte[] input) [0x0001b] in
> C:\Users\codef\source\repos\OptionalyticsFrontend\OptionalyticsFrontend\Shared\Services\Compression.cs:24
> at OptionalyticsFrontend.Client.Pages.Application.GetFilteredOptions
> () [0x00183] in
> C:\Users\codef\source\repos\OptionalyticsFrontend\OptionalyticsFrontend\Client\Pages\Application.razor:310

I've looked at the specified lines over and over, and looked at Google and Stack Overflow for a while, and can't figure it out. The following are the compression/decompression methods used on both back and front end:

```
public static string DecompressString(this byte[] input)
{
    var result = new byte[input.Length];
    using (var source = new MemoryStream(input))
    {
        using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(source,
            CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            decompressionStream.Read(result, 0, input.Length); // <---------- THIS IS THE ERROR LINE
        }
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
}

public static byte[] CompressString(this string inputString)
{
    byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
    using (var result = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var compressionStream = new GZipStream(result,
            CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            compressionStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
            compressionStream.Flush();

        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The following line is where the decompression is called, in my Razor component:

```
var responseString = OptionalyticsFrontend.Shared.Services.Compression.DecompressString(responseBytes);
```

I have looked at, and tried implementing, the following Stack Overflow answers, and none of them worked, I still get the same exception every time.

[GZipStream And DeflateStream will not decompress all bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271260/gzipstream-and-deflatestream-will-not-decompress-all-bytes)

[GZipStream does gzipping but ungzipping file end up with "Unexpected end of data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902654/gzipstream-does-gzipping-but-ungzipping-file-end-up-with-unexpected-end-of-data)

[GZipStream zip file invalid or corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327997/gzipstream-zip-file-invalid-or-corrupted)

[Gzip compression and decompression in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134897/gzip-compression-and-decompression-in-c-sharp)

What is going on here? I am running the front-end Blazor server as .NET Standard and .NET Core (the actual client and shared codes are .NET Standard, server-side is .NET Core)

EDIT: As Andy's comment asked, I added a new stream and tried copying to the new stream, but this results in the same error.

```
public static string DecompressString(byte[] input)
{
    var result = new byte[input.Length];
    using (var newStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var source = new MemoryStream(input))
        {
            using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(source,
                CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(newStream);
            }
        }
        newStream.Position = 0;
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of using `decompressionStream.Read`, create a new memory stream and do `decompressionStream.CopyTo(theNewMemoryStream);`, then do `theNewMemoryStream.Position = 0; Encoding.UTF8.GetString(theNewMemoryStream.ToArray());`

Comment: @Andy Tried it, didn't work. Same exact exception. New code will be added to answer in a second.

Comment: I tried you code and it worked fine. No idea what's going on with your project. If you do this: `var ret = "hello".CompressString().DecompressString();` i get no errors. It works perfect when you use `CopyTo` code above.

Comment: @Andy It turns out it's because in one of my files somewhere in all this exchange of data between servers, I used `await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` instead of `await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<byte[]>()`, and this was breaking everything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, apparently, is that inside of my Application.razor file, I was calling back to my front-end server with `await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` rather than `await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<byte[]>()`, and you want the LATTER because the former somehow transforms the data in a way you don't necessarily expect, that, when converted to a UTF8 string, looks remarkably like a Base64 string. Strange behaviors abound.